# Caption's for checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkbox, caption

One of my grid view's is `5 columns`, two of the columns are checkboxes (row 2 and 3).

One is labeled x, the other is labeled y.  I was wondering what the caption should read to display which check box is displayed.

Below is a caption I have to display the int that is different in every row for the 2nd column which works. But I'm not sure how to do it for checkboxes.

```
gvtask.Caption = gvTask.SlectRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question, preferably with a screenshot, because I don't understand what you want to achieve. What do you mean by "...should read to display which check box is displayed"?

Comment: Its a simple grid view with 5 columns. The above code will work to display in the header what the value in a particular field is.  However, I want to modify it so that the header will display what checkbox is chosen (x or y) which exist in cell 3 and 4 of every row.